# GraphQL defining union before type

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I am trying to define my GraphQL schema using the `graphql` library.  The schema I am trying to achieve, simplified, is this:

```
type TypeA {
  fieldA: String
  fieldAorB: TypeAorB
}

type TypeB {
  fieldB: String
}

union TypeAorB = TypeA | TypeB
```

I am struggling to figure out how to achieve this using the graphql library, given that I can't define the union type before the other types are defined.

Hopefully this snippet highlights my predicament.

```js
import * as graphql from "graphql";

const typeA = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "TypeA",
  fields: { 
    fieldA: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
    fieldAorB: { type: [???] } // what goes here?
  },
});
const typeB = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "TypeB",
  fields: {
    fieldB: { type: graphql.GraphQLString }
  },
});

const typeAorB = new graphql.GraphQLUnionType({
  name: "TypeAorB",
  types: [typeA, typeB],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After re-reading [the documentation](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/):

> When two types need to refer to each other, or a type needs to refer to itself in a field, you can use a function expression (aka a closure or a thunk) to supply the fields lazily.

`fields` can be a closure that can be resolved later.

i.e.,

```js
const typeA = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "TypeA",
  fields: () => ({ // note: closure, not object.
    fieldA: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
    fieldAorB: { type: typeAorB }
  }),
});
```